# Da pra usar uma subquery dentro de um CASE no hadoop

Tags: sql, sql-server, hadoop, hive

Minha tabela ta com uns dados esquisitos e eu precisava dar uma tratada neles na consulta.

Eu tenho um campo de id e um campo de descrição, mas essa descrição as vezes vem "vazia" só com um ' ', mas eu tenho dados associados a essa id.

Minha ideia foi tentar realizar um case que se a descrição for igual a ' ' ele faria um select e pegaria a primeira descrição com mais passagens na tabela.

```
Select
Id_fk,
case 
when descricao = ' '
then (
select descricao 
from tabela 
group by descricao 
order by count desc)
end as descricao
from tabela
limit 1
```

Não sei exatamente se existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso. Se alguém puder me dar uma luz agradeço.

Comment: O que está tentando preencher é um valor default para esta coluna? Se sim o comando [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) parece ser o que precisa

Comment: É basicamente isso. Como eu tenho muitas linhas com esse campo vazio e atribuidas a diversas id_fk diferentes eu pensei em realizar esse case com subquery

Comment: Você quer utilizar o comando `case`  em uma situação que o valor da coluna descrição for a string "" (empty/vazio) ou espaço em branco? Pq da maneira que está escrito é espaço em branco...

Comment: É espaço em branco mesmo. A coluna n ta vindo vazia, ta vindo com um espaço.

Comment: então vai ter que mudar um pouco a solução que enviei, mas é uma correção simples, basta substituir onde eu declarei a `string vazia` para ser `espaço em branco`.